# I want to get from Poland to Frankfurt as cheap as possible

Tags: germany, poland, frankfurt

I want to get from Poland to Frankfurt am Main with a price as cheap as possible. Since I have a student discount (51%) for railway in Poland, I can travel from any city in Poland. However, the discount doesn't count in international trains :/

What would be the best deal to take? I found Szczecin-Berlin buses, but then I cannot find any cool Berlin-Frankfurt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Student train discounts in Germany without BahnCard?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22237/student-train-discounts-in-germany-without-bahncard)

Comment: Poland is quite a big country. Can we assume for the sake of the question that you can travel to any city in Poland for free?

Comment: Do you want to go to Frankfurt am Main or Frankfurt an der Oder?

Comment: I don't think this is exactly a shopping question. "How do I get from Poland to Frankfurt?" is a reasonable question. Modifying that with "I'd like cheap options" is hardly such a stretch.

Comment: Seconded. Just do a search for "cheapest way from" - are all those price-shopping too?

Answer (score 6):

I see this trip on blablacar for 20-ish EUR. If you are OK with a car share I can't see how you could possibly get there cheaper.

Answer (score 3):

Always try the rome2rio.com website. They provide a very good overview of options and prices, anywhere in the world.

Comment: Not very helpful, as the site is not very easy to work for first time users.

Comment: Really? You type in your source and destination cities, and it shows you a map and lists train, airplane, car, bus, etc connections, with duration and price. I don't see what would be difficult with that.

Comment: I got confused by that site, specially trying longer distances and more difficult routes. And I have managed to use many online travel planners. And as far as I have been able to work it and seen from other people, cheap options/alternatives are not its strongest point.

Comment: I think rome2rio is great and very relevant but isn't more of a comment than an actual answer?

Answer (score 3):

For buses inside Germany, and not only, check [Meinferbus/Flixbus](https://meinfernbus.de/en?gclid=CjwKEAjw0pa5BRCLmoKIx_HTh1wSJABk5F_4GkBkPBcKyAOVCFyhoNE6WGbYGQfNrvbOPxsTa85zMBoCSiTw_wcB) (unfortunately they don't have routes to Poland cities (yet)). For example, from Berlin to Frankfurt am Main the price would be **22 Euro**.

So, **Option 1:** **Szczecin-Berlin ; Berling - Frankfurt** by Meinferbus/Flixbus.

Another option (much better I think), there are very cheap flights from **Warsaw Modlin to Bonn/Cologne Airport** via [Ryanair](https://www.ryanair.com/us/en/), **9.99 Euros** (not every flight is this price but you can find it always in 2 weeks range), and from Cologne, to be more specific, from **Leverkusen** (which is apprx. 20 minutes away by local train from the Airport) you have a bus connection, again with Meinferbus/Flixbus for **9 Euro**. In total it would make, say, **20 euros** for you, from Warsaw to Frankfurt.

So, if you can travel so easily inside Poland, Warsaw should not be a problem, and it will be quite a fast travel, Leverkusen-Frankfurt takes only 2 hours and 45 minutes by bus.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest option is to fly from [Gdansk Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gda%C5%84sk_Lech_Wa%C5%82%C4%99sa_Airport) to [Frankfurt Hahn Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankfurt%E2%80%93Hahn_Airport) for ~10 `EUR` on Wizzair:

[image: wizzair azair]

From Frankfurt Hahn Airport you can get to Frankfurt itself by taking [a bus](http://www.bohr.de/linienverkehr/buslinie-hahn-frankfurt) for 15 `EUR`.

Total trip cost: **25 `EUR`**. Total trip time: around 6 hours.